# Visual Studio Code shows not responding dialog every time I start it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I start VS Code for some reason I always get the "Windows is not responding" dialog box even when VS code has loaded in the background. Not sure why I'm seeing that dialog box on when VS code loads and is in the background.  The dialog box usually appears and a couple of seconds or so later VS code loads and is shown in the background.  But sometimes VS code never loads and just see a blank black screen behind the dialog box.  I have tried renaming the "Code" folder in the %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\  and when I restarted VS Code I didn't see the dialog box.

Any suggestions on what to try so I don't have go manually go in and rename/delete the %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code folder each time I start VS Code?